# GCE Http load balancer not reaching instances - UNHEALTHY

Tags: node.js, cloud, load-balancing

I followed the instructions here to setup the load balancer:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/run-on-compute-engine#multiple_instances

My instances work fine, they are accessible via inst.ance.ip.addr:8080 and send a 200 at the root

The load balancer shows:

Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Also the health-check always returns UNHEALTHY:

$gcloud compute backend-services get-health api-service

### shows:

backend: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#####/zones/us-central1-f/instanceGroups/api-server
status:
  healthStatus:
  - healthState: UNHEALTHY
    instance: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#####/zones/us-central1-f/instances/api-server-jg2e
    port: 8080
  - healthState: UNHEALTHY
    instance: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/#####/zones/us-central1-f/instances/api-server-taxd
    port: 8080
  kind: compute#backendServiceGroupHealth

I repeated the setup process like twenty times, from creating the template to the firewall rules. No errors at all while doing so. I coud verify all in the ui of the google cloud console.

I'm going crazy.

Comment: Sandman, not a solution but we're seeing the same issues on our side today. The same rule that we built out months ago is suddenly showing unhealthy despite being able to hit the instance directly and it being up and operational.

Comment: How can we get Google's attention? Is there a forum?

Comment: I opened a ticket with them and flagged this post in it as well. See if this link works. Reviewing other listings in their bugs section seems folks are seeing the same issue. https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=314&q=Type%3DPerformance-Issue&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Resource%20Service%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Log

Comment: Thanks! I added a comment to it. Maybe they will look at it soon.

Answer (score 2):

After submitting the ticket and working through their response providing a debugging blog entry.

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/07/Debugging-Health-Checks-in-Load-Balancing-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html

Our issue wound up being with "Failure 2". After rebooting the server, the necessary routes were not there. However, after doing:

```
/etc/init.d/google-address-manager restart
```

the necessary routes were populated, health checks were good, and the services were then available via public access.

I grabbed the patches from

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/releases

and installed the startup-scripts and daemon packages.

Hope that helps.

Additional note: We were running Debian 8 fully patched at this point

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Question, how do you install the patches if the load balancer needs to spin a new image based on auto-scaling? You can't do this manually every time right? I guees this needs to be in the startup script that the vm launches? Can you please give me some guidance? I come from a windows environment and slowly transitioning to linux. Thanks

Comment: To install the packages I downloaded the .deb packages (we're running debian) and then ran 'dpkg -i package.deb ' I believe its similar with an rpm based distro 'rpm -i' or something. From there, I would imagine if your process is spinning up vms based off of this instance those package updates should go with.

Comment: Hi djneely. I did all those steps, installing the .deb and no luck. These guys from Google don't seem to know what's going on either.. Any idea?

Comment: Sandman sorry to hear that. That's unfortunate. Did you try to reach back out to the Google engineer on that ticket to let them know that the steps didn't work?

Comment: Yes. They can't figure out. I'm going to elevate the ticket with Google. Maybe somebody with more experience in this subject can help.